# how to send current model to the UIHint view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

**Introduction:**

I have a grid with a Field Called Value and that field could be edited by the user.

On my model I have an IEnumerable List with PossibleValues, In case that Possible Values = Empty when users tries to edit (Value field on grid) I should Display a text box by default, but if PossibleValues have Values I'll have to show a DropDownList with all Possible Values.

**The problem:**

Using UIHint on Editing Mode I can display a dropDownList, But I don't know how to send the current model to the Overrieded View...

**The Code:**

Model:

```
public class FamilyParameter
{
    public FamilyParameter()
    {
        PossibleValues = new List<string>();
    }

    [DisplayName("Value")]
    [UIHint("_FamilyParameterValue")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> PossibleValues { get; set; }

    }
}
```

View: Shared/EditorTemplates/_FamilyParameterValue.cshtml

```
@model Bpt.Domain.FamilyParameter
@Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("demo");
```

View: Main

```
<div style="height:270px" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%"> 
                <br />

                @(Html.Telerik().Grid<FamilyParameter>()
                    .Name("GridParam")
                    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(param => param.Code))
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 420px;" })
                    .NoRecordsTemplate("No existen resultados...")
                    .DataBinding(
                        dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                            .Select("_EditMaterial_SelectParameters", Controllers.Valoration,Model)
                            .Update("_EditMaterial_UpdateParameters", Controllers.Valoration,Model)
                        )
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(param => param.Code).Width("75px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;" }).ReadOnly();
                        columns.Bound(param => param.Description).Width("200px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;" }).ReadOnly();
                        columns.Bound(param => param.Value).Width("65px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;" });
                        columns.Command(commands =>
                                        commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)
                            ).Width(60);
                    })
                    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(140))
                    .Footer(false)
                    .Sortable()
                    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
                    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                )

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Solve it !!

Maybe is not the best way, but works 100% great:

**How it Works:**

On my UIHint View I have created a simple Div. Each time that user enter on Edition Mode on my grid I'll execute a Javascript with an ajax post action That will return an url. Then I will execute The url in order to load a PartialView one With a DropDownList and the other with TextBox.

Hope it helps!

**Full Code:**

View: Shared/EditorTemplates/_FamilyParameterValue.cshtml

```
<div id="divFamilyParameterValue"> </div>
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult FamilyPArameterValueDdl(string id)
        {
            var tmpParameter = DetailHvmModel.HvmModel.CurrentArticle.Family.Parameters.Where(e => e.Code == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return PartialView("_FamilyPArameterValueDdl",tmpParameter);
        }
    public ActionResult FamilyPArameterValueTextBox(string id)
    {
        var tmpParameter = DetailHvmModel.HvmModel.CurrentArticle.Family.Parameters.Where(e => e.Code == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_FamilyPArameterValueTextBox", tmpParameter);
    }

    public ActionResult _EditMaterial_EditParameters(string id)
    {

        var tmpParameter = DetailHvmModel.HvmModel.CurrentArticle.Family.Parameters.Where(e => e.Code == id).FirstOrDefault();
        string FamilyParameterValueView;
        // get the parameter that will edit 

        if(tmpParameter.PossibleValues.Any())
        {
              FamilyParameterValueView = Url.Action("FamilyPArameterValueDdl");
        }
        else
        {
             FamilyParameterValueView = Url.Action("FamilyPArameterValueTextBox");
        }


        return Json(new { familyParameterValueView = FamilyParameterValueView });
    }
```

View: Main

```
<div style="height:270px" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%"> 
                <br />

                @(Html.Telerik().Grid<FamilyParameter>()
                      .Name("GridParam")
                      .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(param => param.Code))
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 420px;" })
                      .NoRecordsTemplate("No existen resultados...")
                      .DataBinding(
                          dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                             .Select("_EditMaterial_SelectParameters", Controllers.Valoration,Model)
                                             .Update("_EditMaterial_UpdateParameters", Controllers.Valoration,Model)
                      )
                      .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(param => param.Code).Width("75px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;" }).ReadOnly();
                              columns.Bound(param => param.Description).Width("200px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;" }).ReadOnly();
                              columns.Bound(param => param.Value).Width("65px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;" });
                              columns.Command(commands =>
                                              commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)
                                  ).Width(60);
                          })
                      .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                      .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(140))
                      .Footer(false)
                      .Sortable()
                              .ClientEvents(e => e.OnEdit("OnEditGridParam"))
                      .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
                      .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                      )

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnEditGridParam(e) {
        var item = { id: e.dataItem.Code };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Valoration/_EditMaterial_EditParameters",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: item,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                $.post(data.familyParameterValueView, item, function (partial) { $('#divFamilyParameterValue').html(partial); });   

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }); 


    }

</script>
```

View: _FamilyParameterValueDdl.cshtml

```
@model Bpt.Domain.FamilyParameter

@(Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Value, new SelectList(Model.PossibleValues), new { style="font-size:12px;" }))
```

View: _FamilyParameterValueTextBox.cshtml

```
@model Bpt.Domain.FamilyParameter

@Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you're using Telerik, I use Kendo and the syntax looks the same, here's a grid I use.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("grdDocumentManager")
  //Column Binding
  .Columns(columns =>
               {
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.DocumentNote).Title("Note").Width("20px").ClientTemplate("#if(trim(DocumentNote) != \"\"){#" +
                                                    "<img src=\"/content/i_discuss.gif\" title=\"View Notes\" onclick=\"javascript:showWindow(#=DocumentId#, '#=CaseId#');\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">#}" +
                                                "else{#" +
                                                    "<img src=\"/content/i_rate.gif\" title=\"Add Note\" onclick=\"javascript:showWindow(#=DocumentId#, '#=CaseId#');\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">" +
                                                "#}#");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.DocumentId).Hidden(true);
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.CaseId).Width("50px");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.PresidingJudge).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Presiding Judge: #=value#").Width("20px");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.MagistrateJudge).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Magistrate Judge: #=value#").Width("20px");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.CaseType).Width("20px");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.StatusValue).Width("20px").ClientTemplate("#=Status#").EditorTemplateName("StatusEditor").Title("Status");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.UserName).Width("20px").EditorTemplateName("UserNameEditor");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.CreationDate).Width("50px").Format("{0:g}");
                   columns.Bound(dm => dm.PageCount).Width("20px");
                   columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(200);
               }
  )
  .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                    .Model(m => {
                                    m.Id(dm => dm.DocumentId);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.CaseId).Editable(false);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.CaseType).Editable(false);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.CreationDate).Editable(false);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.DocumentNote).Editable(false);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.MagistrateJudge).Editable(false);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.PresidingJudge).Editable(false);
                                    m.Field(dm => dm.PageCount).Editable(false);

                    })
                    .Update(update => update.Action("DocumentUpdate","Admin"))


             )
  )
```

if you notice on the column bindings it has a property called EditorTemplate there you define the name of your editor (make sure in the editor the name of the control is the same name as the property being bound) and the grid will generate the proper view for it.